# Scroll Magic Pinning and HTML 5 Video tag

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollmagic

I am using Scroll Magic JS. My goal is to take my HTML5 video (below) and use the pin method to make it stick in the background while text scrolls over the top of it.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid">
    <source src="../../pictures/coding.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

My Javascript:

```
var scene_statement = new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#trigger5", duration: 400})
                    .setPin("#bgvid")
                    .addTo(controller);
```

When I do not include the javascript the video works perfectly (obviously not pinning though) and when I use the javascript on an image instead of a video the pinning works perfectly.

When I use the javascript with the video, the video still appears, and it pins, but it does not play. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the video in a `<div>` and pinning that instead?

Comment: Yep, still causes the video to not play.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a jsfiddle or codepen of this for us to observe and inspect this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently ran into this same issue with videos not playing after they've been pinned. I've been able to work around it by forcing the video to play again on the enter event handler. Something like my pseudo-code below should do the trick.

```
.on("enter", function (event) {
    $('video').get(0).play();
 })
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I just added $('video').get(0).play(); after I setup the scene, works fine.